# How to destucture a tuple of records to private values

Tags: f#, tuples, access-control

How do you use a module-level let binding to bind two private values to records in a tuple?

```
type private T = {F:int}
let private a = {F=1}
let private b, private c = {F=2}, {F=3}
```

In this example, `a` works fine, but the bindings for `b` and `c` each fail with the error:

> error FS0410: The type `'T'` is less accessible than the value, member or type `'val patternInput : T * T'` it is used in

Comment: +1 Looks like a leaky abstraction showing through...

Comment: You're not creating a tuple, you're destructuring one. `let private x = {F=2}, {F=3}` creates a tuple (and works fine). You _have_ stumbled upon interesting behavior though.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the terminology clarification. I updated the title and body accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see why this doesn't work, decompile it with Reflector. You're creating a tuple and immediately destructuring it. In debug mode anyway, the intermediate tuple is created as an `internal` field of the enclosing type (an implementation detail of the pattern match). Of course, that makes it more accessible than `T`, which is `private`. I'm curious to know if this is a bug (seems like it).

#### EDIT

It gets weirder...

The following fails to compile (with syntax error), but compiles fine if the types are public and `let`, instead of `let private`, is used.

```
type private T = {a:int; b:int}
let private t = {a=0; b=0}
let private {a=a; b=b} = t //syntax error

type private U() = class end
let private ul = [U()]
let private [u] = ul //syntax error
```

I think it's safe to say destructuring in module-level private `let` bindings has some problems.

Comment: I submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/726415/f-cannot-destucture-a-tuple-of-records-to-private-values) to Microsoft Connect. We'll see what they say.

Comment: @EdwardBrey: I added some more quirky examples.

Comment: Microsoft resolved the bug as "won't fix". This seems to acknowledge  this is indeed a bug, so I accepted Daniel's answer. Too bad they won't fix it, especially considering that F# is so new.

Comment: The workaround is easy, but yeah, it's a bit odd to leave it broken. Hopefully "no" is a momentary answer.

Comment: Easy yes, but messy. :-( I encountered the bug when I was folding rows in a spreadsheet into a tuple of two lists. My workaround was to bind the tuple to a temporary value, and then create the desired individual list values with two additional let bindings.